# (NOT) An Answer

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

**Background:**

I flagged this *answer* https://stackoverflow.com/a/16198105/731947 as **not an answer**.

Full text:

> got the same error, in Windows running with Administrator privileges solved the problem.

And got this resolution:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Also read this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114606/161180

So let's **break it down**:

> got the same error

Sort of "I am having the same problem,"

> <s>got the same error,</s> in Windows ...

Ok, the question is not tagged either [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) or [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) but it's clear it has nothing to do with Windows, and the installation is on Linux from OP's first sentence:

> ... the file to mongodb to the directory **usr/local/mongodb**.

and OP's first line from the code block:

> **./bin/mongod --help** for help and startup options

SO the 'answer' is basically saying: "don't care what you have there, just use Windows and run it with admin privileges, that's what I did"

I get it *could* be declined because it has a few more words there except "got the same error" but just read the question and you see it's **Out Of Topic**, useless and doesn't solve the problem. I don't understand how that answer could help future visitors or anybody else on that matter... *prove me wrong if you must*

Comment: Well... it **is** an answer. A bad, low quality answer, but an answer non-the-less. Downvote it. Comment and explain why it isn't a good or suitable answer to the question. But don't flag it as not-an-answer.

Comment: sorry @Oded but I don't get it... really... it's Off Topic from start

Comment: What do you mean OT from start? The post is giving an answer. Technically - is that not the case?

Comment: I am also not sure why you posted this - all I see is a story, but not a question or issue, or exactly what you are trying to discuss.

Comment: @Oded I used the [discussion] tag, thought that's what it's for. I just wanted to cleanup SO and I get declined on a pretty in-your-face bad answer

Comment: And I've explained why it was declined. Being a bad/low quality/incorrect answer, doesn't suddenly make it a "not an answer". The way to deal with these is to downvote them, comment and when you have enough reputation vote to delete.

Comment: BTW - [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177877/not-an-answer?noredirect=1#comment535820_177877) is the first time you have told us that the flag was declined...

Comment: @Oded I guess *TL;DR;* but I said it was declined in the 'Background'  part of the post (more specifically the second blockquote)

Comment: OK, I stand corrected. Though you seem to have also missed what the decline reason detailed: **flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer**. It is an answer. A wrong answer. A bad answer. But an answer non the less, as you even acknowledged in [your comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177877/not-an-answer#comment535820_177877) - "a pretty in-your-face **bad answer**"

Comment: @Oded bad choice of words on my part, IMHO that actually isn't an answer. Had to post it here because, hell... just look at it... what more does one need to say? and the 'technical' part for declining, maybe it's to sharp. I see that as a *flaw* in the system, how and why would those type of answers allowed to live *so long* ?

Comment: The way the community has decided to deal with such answers is to downvote them. High rep users can vote to delete negative score answers - this removes them. Downvoting and commenting gives the answer OP a chance to understand why the answer is bad and to either edit and correct it or delete it themselves.

Answer (score 11):

You should keep in mind that moderators can't fully grasp how much such an answer is not an answer or a technical inaccuracy.

For the example given

> got the same error, in Windows running with Administrator privileges solved the problem.

This actually is an answer. Sad as it is but well, it is. A moderator can not care now if windows is appropriate or not like you did. It's not just:

> **Same Problem over here!!! HELP!!** - Got the same error. Thanks if you post the answere here. Don't forget to ping me. ***ASAP PLS*** it is urgently. Really.

So please flag answers like these as not an answer, and I'm sure they get removed quickly.

Comment: post the answer* here.......

Comment: "A moderator can not care now if windows is appropriate or not like you did." Actually, it's not the moderators do or can not care, but *false* answers do not get deleted, they get downvoted. If OP was looking for a solution in Linux, then answer regarding a solution in Windows *might* be an answer (a correct one). If it does not fit because of obvious differences between the systems, the answer is simple wrong and needs to be downvoted.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby: Well from a users perspective I can understand the OP and therefore I can understand that some answers that look like "not an answers" do not mean exactly that what the flag stands for. Often when I read the flags text I think: OMG, I could place this onto sooo many answers ;)

Comment: @hakre: Yeah, exactly. It seems like we agree and I just wanted to make sure.